# How to stop text wrapping around floated block?

Tags: html, css

You can see what the issue is by looking [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~eeu41f/)

As you can see the article text is wrapping around the aside, which I've moved relative of it's current position.

Here's the relevant css:

```
aside {
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    right: 275px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,200,0),rgb(0,175,0));
    width: 230px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgb(0,90,0);
}

article {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgb(0,175,0);
    width: 540px;
}
```

I don't want this to happen. I've tried making the position of the aside absolute, which is a solution, but is there a way I can do it this way?

Comment: Don´t use relative positioning for this

Comment: Try changing css of `aside` with `position: absolute;
left: 80px;`

Comment: I've tried that however I want it close to the left hand side of the main article in the centre. Like I've tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `position: relative` works. In simple words: the element occupies the space as it normally would but displays at the specified left/top position relative to its original position.

The solution is to remove relative positioning and use negative left margin instead of left/right:

```
aside {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0,200,0),rgb(0,175,0));
    width: 230px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgb(0,90,0);
    /* remove              */
    /* z-index: -1;        */
    /* position: relative; */
    /* right: 275px;       */
    /* insert              */
    margin-left: -260px;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do, thanks. I'm not entirely sure how the negative margin works though.

Comment: Negative margins allow an element to overlap other elements (or edges as in the above example).

Comment: I think I see how it works, I would just expect changing the margin like that would squish everything up, I guess not! :)

Comment: Generally speaking, setting the margin to a negative number does the opposite of changing the margin to a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that using absolute position, change your styles to this:

```
section {position: relative}
aside {position: absolute; left: -275px; top: 80px;
```

Butm it's only fix of your bad HTML markup, correct way is to float both, `aside` and `article` elements without positioning.